# How do I remove a column from a dataframe using Pandas library for python?

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to remove a column from a dataframe with simple line of code using panda for python.

The name of the column that i'm trying to remove is "Comments"

```
import pandas as pd  
location2 = 'datasets_travel_times.csv'     
travelTime_df= pd.read_csv(location2)  
traveltime_df = travelTime_df.drop('Comments',1)  
traveltime_df
```

It does not give any error; but then I print the dataframe and see that the column "Comments" is still there

Comment: Please provide enough information for us to replicate your code. That way we will be able to better help you. For more information, see [reprex]

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 possible ways:-

First Way:-

```
 travelTime_df.drop(['Comments'], axis=1)
```

Second way:-

```
travelTime_df.drop(columns=['Comments'])
```

Adding link for deep dive:-
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: Third way:- `del travelTime_df['Comments']`